# Batch file says ( was unexpected at this time during if

Tags: batch-file

So I am making a batch file that will generate a random number, keep it in a variable, and then you try to guess it. If you guess lower than the number, it will make your try counter go up by one, and tell you to guess higher, and vice versa. However, when I enter a number, it says ( was unexpected at this time. Can anyone help me?
Here is the code:

```
@echo off
cls
:1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a x = 0
set /a x = %RANDOM:~-3%
endlocal
goto 2
:2
set /p v = Enter your guess:
if %v% lss %x% (
echo Greater than that!
set /a g = %g%+1
title %g% Guesses so far!
goto 2

) else if %v% gtr %x% (
echo Less than that!
set /a g = %g%+1
title %g% Guesses so far!
goto 2

) else if %v% equ %x% (
echo Correct! It was %x%! It also took you %g% guesses to find it!
set /a g = 0
title %g% Guesses so far!
goto 1
)
echo That's not a number!
goto 2
```

Comment: If you read the help file for the SET command you will notice that there is no space between the variable name and the assignment operator.  The usage and examples all clearly show that.

Comment: @Squashman Now, using both of your suggestions, it says `The syntax of the command was incorrect . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
set /a x = 0
:: make it be:
set /a x=0
```

No Space.

Comment: All of the ones that have space  in set /a fix them too. If you'll have spaces it won't work

Answer (score 3):

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

consequently, `v` is not set up and the `if` is interpreted as `if lss 4 (`

You will also have problems with setting a variable like `g` within a ode block (parenthesised sequence of lines). `%g%` will be evaluated at parse-time - it is not interpreted as the run-time value (ie. as code controlling the block is executed)

Pleas see many SO articles on `delayed expansion` my using the `search` facility on the top bar of the page.